# Using JavaScript for machine learning

Tags: javascript, python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Hey there I am new to machine learning and AI .. I like `JavaScript` and would like to use it for the same ..can anyone suggest a good book/resource for the same .. I also read that `python` is a preferred programming language for `AI` and `machine learning` ..can you tell me why ?

Comment: Re Python: it's a relatively simple, high level language which is nevertheless very powerful, has gained traction in the scientific community and has produced some very good libraries in this area. You will be harder pressed to find similar libraries written in or supporting Javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Machine learning will require you to have some data samples for the machine to learn from. For example, if you create neural network with AI, then your neuron weights will be adjusted according to your data samples to make the most optimum weights for firing activation.

In representing the data samples (inputs), the neuron weights, and the outputs, it is usually *preferred* to have programming language which can *represent* and *operate with* **vectors** and **matrices** easily.

`Python` is preferred probably because of its handiness for representing and operating *vectors* and *matrices* (especially using `numpy`) - while at the same time, retaining its high-level OOP language features.

But I would also say language like `Matlab` is equally good (and arguably, in term of representation alone, better) for vector/matrix representation since it is designed especially for that purpose (`Matlab` = **Matrix** laboratory)

Essentially, it is fine for you to create `machine learning` with any language. The more important point in creating such is you understand how the machine should learn. It is of more important than the choice of language itself.

Comment: Does the speed of the language matters in this case ?

Comment: @KaranSinghKochar speed of the language? Mostly no... since AI is not necessarily high performance. Once you know the weights of the neuron, for example, then you do not need to process it with large database anymore, only simple math computation - thus the performance is likely unaffected by the speed of the language. But this also depends on the application. Application like chess really need high performance.